# Difference between rows of a table - MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I try to decrease the rows of a table by its previous value when it exists. For the first row element, consider 0. Could you help me? Create the table below as example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5),
(3, 6),
(3, 7),
(3, 8)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO t2 (id_, value2) VALUES
(1, 0),
(1, 1),
(1, 1),
(2, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 0),
(3, 1),
(3, 1)
```

Comment: If you have 8.0 or 10.2, use `LAG()`.

Answer (score 0):

As before for this correctly to work, you need an order. only ordering it by id_ isn't usually enough to get the correct order done, it would be betterr when you can add another column to order the table correctly so that the right calculations are made having two 2 without any other relation can lead to false results

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
>    id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
>    value1 INT NOT NULL); 
> INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
> (1, 1),
> (1, 2),
> (1, 3),
> (2, 4),
> (2, 5),
> (3, 6),
> (3, 7),
> (3, 8)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id_,value2
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> IF(@id = id_, value1 - @value,0) value2
> ,@value := value1
> ,@id := id_ AS id_
> FROM t1,(SELECT @id:= 0, @value := 0) t1)t2
> ```
>
> ```
> id_ | value2
> --: | -----:
>   1 |      0
>   1 |      1
>   1 |      1
>   2 |      0
>   2 |      1
>   3 |      0
>   3 |      1
>   3 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07306e2e6ec565f6dd34507f8261ca84)*

Comment: Please edit your answer. The text has so many typos it's almost impossible to understand.

Comment: It's the same as last time you need a proper order besides id